# How to display 2 html pages in one html page with javax.swing.text.html.HTMLEditorKit

Tags: java, html

I got in a database some html textparts. Normally they should make one whole html mail body with one html tag and one html close tag and also one for the body.
Sometimes these textparts contain for each line a html open tag and close tag and also a body open and close tag like this:

```
<html>
<body>
test1
</body>
</html>
<html>
<body>
test2
</body>
</html>
```

If I try to display a html page with 2 full webpages like in the example above in google chrome or IE of firefox it displays the content correctly and just displays the second page underneath the first. Also inside a mail client that uses html layout this works out fine.

Now in an application I have to display the content of the mail body in a htmlviewer.
I use javax.swing.text.html.HTMLEditorKit for this and this works fine if I have only one page. But when I got 2 or more it just shows the first one. I tried to embed the code inside another html tag but this didn't solve the issue.

Is there a method to display this webpage without rewriting the html code?
Maybe some option of javax.swing.text.html.HTMLEditorKit ?

Comment: removing the html and body tags and wrapping everything else in a global html and body tags is an option?

Comment: That is the option I like to keep till the last moment. I ask this question to find another, easier option.